# last output of string seems untouched

Tags: java

the last sysout doesn't show that the string changed, anything flew over my head?

This looks for a certain character's position and deletes it from the string:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static int search(String ch, char x) {
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i < ch.length(); i++) {
            if (ch.charAt(i) == x) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static void decal(int x, String A) {
        for (int i = x; i < A.length() -1 ; i++) {
            char a = A.charAt(i);
            a = A.charAt(i +1);
        }
        char e = A.charAt(A.length()-1);
        e = '\0';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("donner une chaine");
        String name;
        Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
        name = sc.nextLine();
        char w;
        System.out.println("donner un caractere");
        w = sc.next().charAt(0);
        int val = search(name, w);
        System.out.println("la position de la lettre " + w + " est "+ val);
        decal(val, name);
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the string should change? I don't see any instruction assigning a new value to the variable `name`. So, how could it change?

Comment: Side issue: your code formatting was pretty awful. Please understand that it's not easy to understand someone else's code, and since you want us to understand it and  help you, you really don't want to make this process any harder than it has to be. Please put in the effort to post well-formatted code in the future. It doesn't take much effort to do this and it is time well spent and is much appreciated by site members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, you don't need the `decal` method at all, you can simply use the [String.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) method to replace the character you need with an empty character. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char w;
    System.out.println("donner une chaine");
    Scanner sc =  new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("donner un caractere");
    w = sc.next().charAt(0);
    int val = search(name, w);
    System.out.println("la position de la lettre " + w + " est "+ val);
    name = name.replace(name.charAt(val)+"", ""); //replace old character (notice conversion to String) with empty String.
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

After running your `search` method, we know the position of the character of interest, so we can simply use the replace() method to give the character at that position as the character to replace, convert that to String, and the empty String as the new replacement. This will give following output:

```
donner une chaine
hello
donner un caractere
e
la position de la lettre e est 1
hllo
```

I believe you were hoping to use something like:

```
name = name.replace(name.charAt(val), '\0');
```

But be aware that like this you are replacing the character with a '\0' character that will be there (i.e. it would be 'h\0llo'), although you will not see it when you will be printing the statement due to the cast to String that is happening in the background and the output will look correct. If you want, you can easily check that by converting your changed String to charArray and checking if it contains '\0' character. For example, simple check:

```
    String name1 = name.replace(name.charAt(val), '\0');    // h\0llo
    String name2 = name.replace(name.charAt(val)+"", "");   // hllo
    String name3 = name.replace(name.charAt(val)+"", "\0"); // h\0llo
    System.out.print(name1.equals(name2)); //false
    System.out.print(name1.equals(name3)); //true
```

Therefore, I would recommend to use the first method given, (with conversion to String).